# Standard way dynamically set theme based Images for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am currently setting the images for theme like this in the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    setThemeIcons();
}

private void setThemedIcons()
{
    Uri u;
    if ((Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        u = new Uri("/Images/img_dark.png", UriKind.Relative);
    }
    else
    {
        u = new Uri("/Images/img_light.png", UriKind.Relative);
    }
    btnSessionSearch.Source = new BitmapImage(u);
}
```

This seems an inferior coding to me. The main reason is I will have to do this for every image in the application that is going to be theme sensitive.

Ideal way is to bind the image directly in the XAML. How to do it so that it is theme aware ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ThemedImageConverter you can use it in this way:

```
<Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource themedImageConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource PhoneBackgroundColor}}"
DataContext="/WP7SampleProject4;component/Images/{0}/appbar.feature.camera.rest.png" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Prepare a ValueConverter which will add 'dark' or 'light' suffix to the file path and use it when binding the image source property.

More info about `IValueConverter` interface and using converters in XAML can be found in the Internet, eg. on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [TheCodeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/234337/Data-Binding-Using-IValueConverter-in-Silverlight).

Comment: i kinda figured out myself, but a sample code would be really helpful for me.. at least the xaml part.